# Program not using all of CPU?

Tags: c++, windows, cpu

I wrote a simple program in C++ like:

```
while(1){var+=1;var-=1;}
```

and ran it, but it seems to only use 25% of CPU.

How can I increase the amount of CPU that my program will use, to 95%?

Comment: I duped this to a C question since this question doesn't actually involve C++ specifics. (discussion here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20227431#20227431)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're running this on a 4-processor system. You *are* using 100% of the CPU on one core. To use the other cores, you will have to write a multi-thread version of your application.

Multi-threading is very complicated, but there are lots of good tutorials out there; just hit up Google. Good luck!

Comment: So basically, I have 4 cores, which means I need to set up 4 threads and have each thread run that same code?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Exactly how you do it (processes versus threads) depends on which OS you're using; Windows and *nix systems (Unix, Linux, Mac OS X, Android, etc.) handle these things differently.